# Maven doesn't build but in Eclipse it works

Tags: java, eclipse, facebook, maven

I am trying to create executable jar in Eclipse with Maven. My program perfectly works if I run it in Eclipse but if try to build it with  Maven it will write this error and build failed. Can someone please help me!!!

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile 
 (default-compile) on project myProject: Compilation failure
 [ERROR] C\FacebookGet.java:[34,25] error: for-each not applicable to expression type
```

Here is code where is error

```
Connection<Post> result = fbclient.fetchConnection(
            "********/feed", Post.class);

    Session session = GeneralSession.getSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    34 - for (List<Post> page : result) {
    35 -   for (Post apost : page) {
    36 -     if (apost.getMessage() != null
```

Comment: What is `Connection`? Link to the api?

Comment: Yes. Connection to facebook funpage

Comment: That's not what I meant. Do you have a link to the API you're using, especially to the `Connection` class?

Comment: To use an object on the right side of the `:` in a for-each loop, that object must be of a type that implements interface `java.lang.Iterable`. If the type `Connection` does not implement `Iterable`, then you get an error. Does `Connection` implement `Iterable`?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Iterator implemented in this Connection class? I guess it wouldn't work in Eclipse if it wasn't, but who knows, check that. Also, check pom.xml and find java source, maybe Eclipse uses different java than maven, should be something like this:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
  <source>1.8</source>
  <target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner in Java.
I think variable result can be itterrated

```
    Iterator<List<Post>> com.restfb.Connection.iterator()   
    Connection<Post> result - main.FacebookGet.start(String)
```

It really works in Eclipse. Or can me please someone write how to change it from for-each to regular?

Comment: [`Connection`](http://restfb.com/javadoc/com/restfb/Connection.html) implements `Iterable`, so it should work with the enhanced `for`. Do you use different library versions?

Comment: I change it to basic for and it works! So thank you!!!                     List<Post> page = result.getData();
 for (int help=0; help<page.size(); help++) {
  page.get(help).getMessage();